# Talend tRESTClient does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, talend, afabstractrestclient

I have a Talend job which has an input CSV file which needs to be converted to a JSON format and then using a tRESTclient/tREST , make a HTTP call request and post data.

In the current job, I have an Elasticsearch server installed on my local machine and provided that URL.

I was able to convert the files to JSON format and also verified with a tlogrow component but unable to post data.

(P.S: I was able to post data using a bulk Java code, loading jar files and making HTTP call and sending parameters using a tJAVArow component. So no issue with my localhost and posting data.)

Comment: For some reasons these REST / webservice components may require you to have JDK installed, AND configured in talend. Once we've done that it started to work.

Comment: To elasticsearch to work in talend, they recommend tElasticsearch componant. But, I'm struggling with it! :(

Answer (score 0):

After converting the data from input file to JSON format, set the context variable with your JSON data and then make the rest call. You can add the context variable in the HHTP Body. example : context.json_post without double quotes.